# Generate same line changing integer PHP

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I want to make sitemap of my website and it has thousands of static pages like `ID?=1` so I decided to make php script which automatically generate these links

Or do you have any idea how I can do like this

MY website pages are like

```
http://example.com/index.php?pn=4
http://example.com/index.php?pn=5 
.
.
```

Now I want to paste same lines again and again but changing the numbers after =

Comment: Please tell me instead of down vote I can't speak English well so I can't explain it

Comment: You can use an online tool like [this](http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/) to generate HTML/XML sitemaps for your site.

Comment: With a loop to add the number

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger It has limit of 500 Pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<?php

for($i=0;$i<=6;$i++) { // changes the value of 6 according to your needs

echo '<p><a href="http://example.com/index.php?pn='.$i.'">http://example.com/index.php?pn='.$i.'</a></p>';

} ?>
```

Comment: I did it BTW Thanks for the help